How to make a single g8 20w 120v dimmable led bulb work
What do I need to do to make a single G8 20W 120V dimmable led bulb work? I want to put the bulb in a glass tube and seal it for lighting inside a vintage water fountian.. I'm replacing what I believe was a halogen that was there before. The bulb burned out and the old glass tube broke so I am starting fresh with a different tube and led bulb.

I wouldnt put 120V in a fountain. Instead, look at making something from 12V leds, or led strips or ropes.
Or just buy external, submersible lights. They are manufactured for this purpose. If you cant find one, look in a pool shop.
